# React on auto scroll on load more items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I am facing wierd issue. I have laod more button which add 5 items to array and display it.

It works fine on first load more, but when i scroll manually after that load more button stays at same position and items load above and window autoamatically scroll to adjust postion of my button.

This is example code.

```
const getRandomData = n =>
  new Array(n).fill(0).map(i => ({
    id: Math.random() * 1000,
    value: Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .substring(7)
  }));

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getRandomData(count).map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.value}</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={e => setCount(count + 5)}>Load more</button>
      <div style={{ height: 400 }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is codesandbox working example.

If you load more 2-3 times and then scroll manually. After this if i click load more then window scrolls autoamtically.

https://codesandbox.io/s/343wmr8v66

Comment: That is the default behaviour of the browser. How would you want it to work instead?

Comment: new items should load below. and window should not scroll. the way it loads first time. the way it behave before manual scroll.

Comment: @Tholle i can think way of doing it by changing scroll position but i feel that's dirty way. is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: I am running the codepen on Chrome 73, window does not auto scroll.

Comment: @AseemGautam You need to load more untill scroll bar comes up then manually scroll once. after this it will auto scroll. before manual scroll it is working as expected.

Comment: if you want to keep the same position, You can create a useScrollPosition hook that saves the scroll position prior to updates, or use getSnapshotBeforeUpdate with classes. then just after the push, set the scroll position to whatever you'd like

Comment: Maybe something like : https://codesandbox.io/s/m72wvynqr9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is called Scroll Anchoring.

You can disable this behaviour by adding:

```
overflow-anchor: none;
```

to your CSS.

Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor

Answer (score 0):

This is fix i applied not sure it's efficient one.
I have stored scroll postion on button click and set on scroll back to that postion if scroll is set.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const getRandomData = n =>
  new Array(n).fill(0).map(i => ({
    id: Math.random() * 1000,
    value: Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .substring(7)
  }));
let scroll;
const onScroll = () => {
  if (scroll) {
    window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
    scroll = null;
  }
};
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    },
    () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    },
    []
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getRandomData(count).map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.value}</div>
      ))}
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          scroll = window.scrollY;
          setCount(count + 5);
        }}
      >
        Load more
      </button>
      <div style={{ height: 400 }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```